# How to keep WebRTC adapter.js updated in a project using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, webrtc

I am confused about how to make use of `npm` to keep the `adapter.js` updated in my project.

I have followed the instructions on https://github.com/webrtc/adapter and get the `webrtc-adapter` installed using the node command `npm install webrtc-adapter`.

A directory of `node_modules` is created and inside there are `package.json`, `out` folder, and other files and folders. Since the `adapter.js` is inside the `out` folder, I have to copy it to my project libraries folder `lib/js/adapter.js`.

However, if I run the `npm update` in the future, it should only update the `adapter.js` inside the `node_modules/out` but not `lib/js/adapter.js`. Then I have to copy it again. Is there anyway I could make the update apply to the `lib/js/adapter.js` directly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [webrtc samples repository](https://github.com/webrtc/samples) solves this by having an postinstall npm hook. See [here](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/package.json#L23)